# Is this photo depicting Dalits from India genuine?

Tags: india, photography

Imran H Sarker said in a tweet:

> Wake up INDIA! This is 21st century, not 14th! YOU are not better than
> ISIS until standing for this Dalit family!
>
> [image: Dalits in India]

Comment: see the wider view and video and article here: http://www.dnaindia.com/india/report-police-allegedly-strip-dalit-family-naked-in-up-for-filing-complaint-2133171

Comment: Can you please clarify what the claim is? It seems to be a remarkable protest but not a remarkable claim. Yes, it says they are a Dalit family, but this seems more an attempt at putting a shock value picture on the site than a genuine doubt.

Comment: @Sklivvz Whether this photo was taken in India and whether the people shown in the photo are dalits or not. The link Dave shared answers it. You may delete or put it on hold. My problems solved. I have no need of it anymore.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin They are in Gautam Buddh Nagar, Utter Pradesh, India. They are dalit. The real question is did the people (not all shown in the OP) strip voluntarily or involuntarily or some voluntarily and some involuntary, and if any were stripped involuntarily, were they stripped by the police or crowd?

Comment: What we *can* answer is whether the photo is genuine (e.g. it actually represents dalits in india and it's not staged or faked). What we can't really answer is what the tweeter implies without saying in their tweet is correct.

Comment: @Sklivvz That's what I asked.

Comment: @Sklivvz It's clearly genuine as shown by the wide view video version, the issue is were any clothes removed against anyone's will?

Comment: @DavePhD that would make it about motivations, let's not go there

Comment: @DavePhD That wasn't my issue when I asked. But it's my issue now. Should I edit this question or ask another?

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin please do neither. This question has an answer already, and also we do not allow questions about motivations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's genuine as proven by the video in the DNAIndia post [Police allegedly strip Dalit family naked in UP for filing complaint](http://www.dnaindia.com/india/report-police-allegedly-strip-dalit-family-naked-in-up-for-filing-complaint-2133171).

> Police in Greater Noida's Gautam Buddh Nagar allegedly stripped a Dalit family naked for attempting to file a complaint. Subsequently, a video of the incident has gone viral on social media.
>
> According to The Hindu, Sunil Gautam and his wife were stripped naked publicly by the Dankaur police after they insisted on filing a police complaint. They were later arrested and locked up in jail.

...

> The video above seems to be inconclusive and incomplete. It is unclear whether the family was stripped or themselves disrobed. Nevertheless, the inordinate reaction of the police and public can be seen clearly. Indeed, one woman is being dragged along the crowd and also gets stripped in the melee. A child also seems to have been stripped of his clothes.

Comment: From the article: "The video above seems to be inconclusive and incomplete. It is unclear whether the family was stripped or themselves disrobed"

Comment: @Sklivvz the question is only whether or not the photo is genuine

Comment: @Sklivvz edited to give more info

Comment: Thank you - for the record, just because it comes off a realistic video, that doesn't "prove" it's genuine (the rest of the article does claim that the events actually happened though so, the answer is much better now).

Comment: @Sklivvz I thought you (when you changed the question to "genuine") meant as opposed to photoshopped or cut and paste, but maybe you mean something else by "genuine".

Comment: Ah, no, there's a meta question about this: unfortunately the English language does not help here. Genuine can also mean "not staged, not acted" for example. Think of a "flying saucer" photo, it can be faked in many ways, not only photoshop :-)